# google spreadsheets(google excel) Why is my picture being displayed incorrectly in Html View?

Tags: google-sheets

Whenever I add a picture to google spreadsheets in editor mode It always appears lower when viewed in Html Mode. Is their a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instruct Google Spreadsheet engine with ease how you want the images to render by using this syntax:

```
To retain aspect ratio while increasing / decreasing the cell size:
    =IMAGE("URL") 
To make the image stretch and fit all edges of the cell:
    =IMAGE("URL",2)
To make the image keep its original size:
    =IMAGE("URL",3) 
To manually set the image size (replace 50,50 with desired dimensions):
    =IMAGE("URL",4,50,50)
```

Now to answer your question more directly. There are several reasons why this can happen. This comes to how Google are actually translating the spreadsheet and rendering it as HTML.

With that said, it is hard to answer your question with the correct answer while not being able to look at the spreadsheet and the output of the html.

**Update**
Looking at your source:
[image: Problems with CSS]

The problem is that the CSS that is outputted generates topå and left values that makes the image be off by the y axiz.

Here is a method to edit the CSS in Google Spreadsheet if you are familiar with it: http://lifehacker.com/387849/style-your-google-docs-with-css

If you are not familiar with it its probably not much help, but anyway!

If you find this answer helpful please tick accept and up it, i need it :-)

Comment: I cant post images as my reputations not high enough but i could just give you the site, go to "grandpa muto" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TazmJLQpekOuWDdxEoun2FPH0Xgh1tiPJdTfioBnj3E/htmlview?sle=true# @Dan-Levi Tømta

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped! @Dan-Levi Tømta

Comment: Glad to hear i could help you. Please click to up arrow on my answer. I have been a lazy dog and cant post questions since i havent contributed enough. This will help me :) haha :) If there is anything else feel free to ask me.